# What does ctx.stub.getState(KEY) return when no state exists for 'KEY'?

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

In the Commercial Paper example of Hyperledger Fabric, there is a StateListImpl class that implement getState like this:

```java
    @Override
    public State getState(String key) {

        CompositeKey ledgerKey = this.ctx.getStub().createCompositeKey(this.name, State.splitKey(key));

        byte[] data = this.ctx.getStub().getState(ledgerKey.toString());
        if (data != null) {
            State state = this.deserializer.deserialize(data);
            return state;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But, when I call this `StateListImpl.getState` function with a Key that doesn't exists, the condition `data != null` its true (and an exception is ocurring inside deserializer), so it seems that `ctx.stub.getState(ledgerKey)` is not returning null. I've searched in fabric documentation (and in its [javadocs](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-chaincode-java/master/api/org/hyperledger/fabric/shim/ChaincodeStub.html#getState-java.lang.String-)) and doesn't say anything about what happens when `key` isn't in the ledger.

Well, what returns `ctx.stub.getState(KEY)` if `KEY` state is not in the ledger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java is not enough checking for null, you have to check also for the length of the byte array, I'm using the following code:

```
final String data = stub.getStringState(id);
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(data)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(
      String.format("The item %s doesn't exist", id)
    );
 }
```

If we look closer at **StringUtils.isEmpty** it checks for the length

```
public static boolean isEmpty(CharSequence cs) {
    return cs == null || cs.length() == 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I suspect that for `getState` it is similar. Is very anoying that one official example doesn't face this in a good manner.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the getState does not return a null value. Instead, it returns an object that is 'undefined'.
So if you change your code to `getState(key)===undefined` then it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking for java smart contract